# Column pruning on parquet files defined as an external table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

Context: We store historical data in Azure Data Lake as versioned parquet files from our existing Databricks pipeline where we write to different Delta tables. One particular log source is about 18 GB a day in parquet. I have read through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-lake-query-data#optimize-your-query-performance) and executed some queries using Kusto.Explorer on the external table I have defined for that log source. In the query summary window of Kusto.Explorer I see that I download the entire folder when I search it, even when using the project operator. The only exception to that seems to be when I use the take operator.

Question: Is it possible to prune columns to reduce the amount of data being fetched from external storage? Whether during external table creation or using an operator at query time.

Background: The reason I ask is that in Databricks it is possible to use the SELCECT statement to only fetch the columns I'm interested in. This reduces the query time significantly.

Comment: For external table with partitions, the "Downloaded Size" metric seems to be erroneous, presenting the total data size, regardless of the selected columns, **However** the queries performance indicates that columns` pruning **does happen**. For external tables without partitions the "Downloaded Size" metric seem to be fine.

Comment: We are partitioning based on date. You're right, the query performance significantly improves when using the project operator. This is also reflected in CPU usage on the cluster when querying. I was mislead by Kusto.Explorer - Query summary. Great that ADX supports this! Thank you David!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David wrote above, the optimization does happen on Kusto side, but there's a bug with the "Downloaded Size" metric - it presents the total data size, regardless of the selected columns. We'll fix. Thanks for reporting.